# For loops over dates to download tables and combine them in one function

Tags: r, for-loop, datetime, if-statement

my code look something like this:

```
### Loading needed packages 

install.packages(c("tidyverse", "httr2"))
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

### Function which I use

get_earnings <- function(from_date, to_date) {
  str_c(
    "https://api.benzinga.com/api/v2.1/calendar/earnings?token=1c2735820e984715bc4081264135cb90&parameters[date_from]=",
    from_date,
    "&parameters[date_to]=",
    to_date,
    "&parameters[tickers]=&pagesize=1000"
  ) %>%
    request() %>%
    req_headers(accept = "application/json") %>%
    req_perform() %>%
    resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>%
    pluck("earnings") %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    type_convert()
}


### Use function for one month / the function does not work for more than 10 days
### -> splitting the month in three parts 

df1<- get_earnings(from_date = "2022-12-21", to_date = "2022-12-31")
df2<- get_earnings(from_date = "2022-12-11", to_date = "2022-12-20")
df2<- get_earnings(from_date = "2022-11-01", to_date = "2022-12-10")

### I need more than one year with this function 
### I could do it by copy and pasting -> huge chance of error

### So i want to write a function which does it on anually base 

### Define function

extract_data_year <- function(year) {
  year <- as.character(year)
  df_whole <- data.frame()
  for ( i in 1:9) {
    
    # Months 1 - 9
    if ( i <= 9) {
      i_1 <- paste0(0,i)
      
      # Month Part I
      from_date = paste0(year,"-",i_1,"-","01") 
      to_date = paste0(year,"-",i_1,"-","10") 
      df_1 <-get_earnings(from_date = from_date, to_date = to_date)
      
      # Month Part II
      from_date = paste0(year,"-",i_1,"-","11") 
      to_date = paste0(year,"-",i_1,"-","20") 
      df_2 <-get_earnings(from_date = from_date, to_date = to_date)
      
      # Month Part III
      from_date = paste0(year,"-",i_1,"-","21") 
      to_date = paste0(year,"-",i_1,"-","28") 
      df_3 <-get_earnings(from_date = from_date, to_date = to_date)
      
    
      df <- rbind(df_1,df_2,df_3)
    }
    else if(i > 9) { # Months 10-12
      # i defined as in for loop
      
      # Month Part I
      from_date = paste0(year,"-",i,"-","01") 
      to_date = paste0(year,"-",i,"-","10") 
      df_1 <-get_earnings(from_date = from_date, to_date = to_date)
      
      # Month Part II
      from_date = paste0(year,"-",i,"-","11") 
      to_date = paste0(year,"-",i,"-","20") 
      df_2 <-get_earnings(from_date = from_date, to_date = to_date)
      
      # Month Part III
      from_date = paste0(year,"-",i,"-","21") 
      to_date = paste0(year,"-",i,"-","28") 
      df_3 <-get_earnings(from_date = from_date, to_date = to_date)
      
      
      df <- rbind(df_1,df_2,df_3)
      
    }
    df_whole <- rbind(df,df_whole)
  }
  return(df_whole)
}

### Works for Months 1-9 but doesnt work for 10-12

df1 <- extract_data_year(2022)
```

My questions:

Why does it not download the month 10-12?

As you see, the max date is 28, because of the february. If the funtion would get inpurt on february 30 or 31 it would not work. Is there a possibilty to adapt the end of each month like 28,30,31?

Thank you

Combine downloads

adapt for each month the correct end

function partly does not work

Comment: Take a look at the `lubridate` package.  Especially `floor_date` and `ceiling_date`.  Also, make sure your general function can handle leap years correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

get_earnings <- function(from_date, to_date) {
  str_c(
    "https://api.benzinga.com/api/v2.1/calendar/earnings?token=1c2735820e984715bc4081264135cb90&parameters[date_from]=",
    from_date,
    "&parameters[date_to]=",
    to_date,
    "&parameters[tickers]=&pagesize=1000"
  ) %>%
    request() %>%
    req_headers(accept = "application/json") %>%
    req_perform() %>%
    resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>%
    pluck("earnings") %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    type_convert()
}

date_Init <- as.Date("2022-01-01")
date_End <- as.Date("2023-01-01")
month_Vec <- seq(from = date_Init, to = date_End, by = "months")

ten_Days_Chunk <- seq(from = month_Vec[1], to = month_Vec[2] - 1, length.out = 3)

for(i in 2 : 12)
{
  ten_Days_Chunk <- c(ten_Days_Chunk, seq(from = month_Vec[i], to = month_Vec[i + 1] - 1, length.out = 3))
}

list_DF <- list()

for(i in 1 : (length(ten_Days_Chunk) - 1))
{
  print(i)
  list_DF[[i]] <- get_earnings(from_date = ten_Days_Chunk[i], to_date = ten_Days_Chunk[i + 1])
}

list_DF[[35]]
# A tibble: 100 x 25
   currency date       date_con~1   eps eps_est eps_p~2 eps_s~3 eps_s~4 eps_t~5 excha~6 id    impor~7 name  notes period perio~8 revenue reven~9
   <chr>    <date>          <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 USD      2022-12-30          1  0         NA   NA         NA      NA GAAP    NASDAQ  628b~       0 OKYO~ FXC   H1        2022  0           NA
 2 USD      2022-12-30          1 -0.3       NA   -0.97      NA      NA GAAP    NASDAQ  60a3~       0 MEDI~ FXC   H1        2022  2.57e7      NA
 3 USD      2022-12-30          1 -0.2       NA   NA         NA      NA GAAP    NYSE    611c~       0 Onio~ NA    H1        2022  1.27e8      NA
 4 USD      2022-12-30          1 -0.75      NA   NA         NA      NA GAAP    NASDAQ  6093~       0 Blue~ NA    H1        2022  1.99e6      NA
 5 USD      2022-12-30          1 -1.73      NA   -0.9       NA      NA GAAP    NASDAQ  6193~       0 Seco~ Earn~ H1        2022  1.74e8      NA
 6 USD      2022-12-30          1 -0.28      NA   -0.3       NA      NA Adj     NASDAQ  61b9~       0 Uxin  Earn~ Q2        2023  8.70e7      NA
 7 USD      2022-12-29          1 -0.22      NA   NA         NA      NA Adj     NASDAQ  6127~       0 Miss~ NA    H1        2022  3.98e8      NA
 8 USD      2022-12-29          1  0         NA   NA         NA      NA GAAP    NASDAQ  61ce~       0 Merc~ NA    H1        2022  7.83e5      NA
 9 USD      2022-12-29          1 -0.01      NA   -0.01      NA      NA GAAP    OTC     6285~       0 Timb~ NA    Q4        2022  0           NA
10 USD      2022-12-29          1 -0.01      NA    0.16      NA      NA GAAP    AMEX    61c1~       0 Barn~ NA    Q4        2022  8.38e6      NA
# ... with 90 more rows, 7 more variables: revenue_prior <dbl>, revenue_surprise <dbl>, revenue_surprise_percent <dbl>, revenue_type <chr>,
#   ticker <chr>, time <time>, updated <int>, and abbreviated variable names 1: date_confirmed, 2: eps_prior, 3: eps_surprise,
#   4: eps_surprise_percent, 5: eps_type, 6: exchange, 7: importance, 8: period_year, 9: revenue_est
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
```